# How to save the specific textboxes with special order to a text file?

Tags: c#, textbox, savefiledialog

I want to use a button to save my contents. Here is my code! I can't see anything show on the text file. Can someone help me? By the way? How to choose the saving location whatever i choose? It's seems to save in the debug folder.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.FileName = "Parameters.txt";
    save.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
    System.IO.StreamWriter File = new System.IO.StreamWriter(save.FileName);
    if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {

        File.Write("===========parameters===========" + "\r\n");
        File.Write("Number of teeth: " + textBox1.Text + "\r\n"); 
          *
          *
          *
          *
        File.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Saving succeed(Parameters)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working for you.  I just created a program with your code, and it works fine.  You are getting the message box saying it saved fine?  Make sure and look in the Debug or Release folder for the correct version of your save file.

Comment: It's working for me as well.

Comment: but I didn't see anything on my text file.;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
     // save.FileName = "Parameters.txt";
        save.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
       if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
       {
           using (System.IO.StreamWriter File = new System.IO.StreamWriter(save.FileName))
           {
               File.Write("===========parameters===========" + "\r\n");
               File.Write("Number of teeth: " + "\r\n");

               // File.Close();
               MessageBox.Show("Saving succeed(Parameters)");
           }
        }
```